# extend Newtonsoft.Json.JObject class

Tags: c#, json

I want to extend the Newtonsoft.Json.JObject class to add some method. the JObject just have getValue() method, I want to extend getString(), getInt, getDouble, getDate ..., code like below:

class JSONObject:JObject
    {
        JObject jo=new JObject();

```
    public JSONObject(JObject jo)
    {
        this.jo = jo;
    }
    public  JSONArray GetJSONArray(string key)
    {
        return (JSONArray)jo.GetValue(key);
    }

    public string getString(string key)
    {
        return (string)jo.GetValue(key).ToString();
    }

    public int getInt(String key)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(getString(key));
    }

    public long getLong(String key)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64(getString(key));
    }

    public bool getBool(String key)
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(getString(key));
    }

    public double getDouble(String key)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(getString(key));
    }

    public DateTime getDateTime(String key,IFormatProvider format)
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(getString(key),format);
    }

    public DateTime getDateTime(String key)
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo dtFormat = new 
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
        dtFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
        return Convert.ToDateTime(getString(key),dtFormat );
    }


}
```

all is ok except I use the JObject.parse() method, because the JObject.parse() is return a JObject, the JObject is the parent class of JSONObject, it can't be cast to JSONObject. so can't parse string to JSONObject through my JSONObject class. I want my class fully extend the JObject class with my own method, anyone can give me suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like so

```
JObject o = ...;
return o.Value<string>();
```